# Which ligands would be exchanged in this reaction?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I have this reaction and need to state what the products would be:

$\ce{(CF3)2PH + [W(CO)5(THF)] -> }$

THF stands for Tetrahydrofuran.

Would this just be a simple ligand exchange, and if so which ones would be exchanged? How would you know?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) which shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Furthermore, what are your own thoughts on the matter? What do you think will happen and why?

Comment: I think that the two CF3 groups will replace either two of the CO or one CO and the THF. But i don't know which one or how to work it out.

Comment: Why do you think the CF3 groups will replace a ligand?

Answer (score 2):

Complexes like $\ce{M(CO)5(solv)}$ are typically generated by photolysis ($\lambda$ = 350 nm) of $\ce{M(CO)6}$ in the presence of a non-inert solvent. This proceeds through a highly reactive "naked" $\ce{M(CO)5}$ intermediate.

$$\ce{W(CO)6 + solv ->[h\nu] W(CO)5(solv) + CO}$$

1. When offered another ligand $\mathrm{L}$, the weakest bond  ligand in the $\ce{W(CO)5(solv)}$ complex is replaced. This is THF.
2. Taking the lone pair on the phosphorous atom into account, is is conceivable that $\ce{(CF3)2PH}$ will do the job:

$$\ce{W(CO)5(thf) + (CF3)2PH -> W(CO)5((CF3)2PH) + THF}$$